# Why does the R type provider throw an exception when it does not in a similar installation?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have two computers with seemingly equal code and configurations, one compiles a solution, the other does not.

The problem is related to the `R Type Provider`.

This is the code:

```
/// Path to project data folder.
[<Literal>]
let projDataPath = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"\data\"

[<Literal>]
let jsonPath = projDataPath + "fractal.json"
type PathInfo = JsonProvider<Sample=jsonPath>

/// Csv provider for files with information about assets
type AssetsInfo = CsvProvider<Sample="AssetInfoFS.csv", // must be a Literal
                              HasHeaders=true,
                              ResolutionFolder=projDataPath,
                              AssumeMissingValues=false,
                              CacheRows=false>

[<Literal>]
let configPath = projDataPath + "config.json"
type Cnfg = JsonProvider<Sample=configPath>
```

Both computer are running `Windows 10`, the one where the code does not compile is running the `Home` version, the other one is running the `Pro` version.

Both computers have `Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.7.2` installed.

**Configuration**

**Application:**

Target F# runtime: `4.4.3.0`

Target Framework: `.NET Framework 4.6.1`

Output type: `Console Application`

**Build:**

Platform Target: `Any CPU`

Other flags: `Prefer 32-bit`

**Installed packages:**

`R.NET Community v1.65`

`R.NET Community,FSharp v1.65`

`RProvider v1.1.2.0`

**R version:**

Tried with `R 3.4.3` and `R 3.5.0`, in both cases the 32-bit and 64-bit versions were installed.

**Error message:**

```
parse error FS3053: error : The type provider constructor has thrown an exception: Initialization of R.NET failed
1>FSC: warning FS3005: Referenced assembly 'C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\RProvider.dll' has assembly level attribute 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute' but no public type provider classes were found
1>Done building project "Fractal13.fsproj" -- FAILED.
```

There were some old questions on the web and in SO related to this but no clear solution. Any suggestions for solving this problem?

**EDIT:**

Following Tomas Petricek's suggestion in a comment I obtained the following log:

```
[5/26/2018 7:45:20 AM] [Pid:12476, Tid:44, Apid:1] initAndGenerate: starting
[5/26/2018 7:45:20 AM] [Pid:12476, Tid:44, Apid:1] Starting server 'C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\RProvider.Server.exe' with arguments 'RInteropServer_12476_457625_1311358896 "C:\Users\fsald\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpFB99.tmp"' (exists=true)
[5/26/2018 7:45:20 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Starting 'RProvider.Server' with arguments '[|"RInteropServer_12476_457625_1311358896";
  "C:\Users\fsald\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpFB99.tmp"|]'
[5/26/2018 7:45:20 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Registering RInteropServer at channel 'RInteropServer_12476_457625_1311358896'
[5/26/2018 7:45:20 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Ready for connections..
[5/26/2018 7:45:20 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Attempting resolution for 'RDotNet, Version=1.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Probing locations: C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Accord.3.8.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Accord.MachineLearning.3.8.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Accord.MachineLearning.GPL.3.8.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Accord.Math.3.8.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Accord.Statistics.3.8.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Deedle.1.2.5\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\DynamicInterop.0.7.4\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\FSharp.Date.0.3\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\MathNet.Numerics.4.4.1\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\numl.0.8.26.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\R.NET.Community.1.6.5\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\R.NET.Community.FSharp.1.6.5\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Found assembly, checking version! (C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\R.NET.Community.1.6.5\lib\net40\RDotNet.dll)
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] ...version matches, returning!
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Attempting resolution for 'DynamicInterop, Version=0.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Probing locations: C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Accord.3.8.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Accord.MachineLearning.3.8.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Accord.MachineLearning.GPL.3.8.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Accord.Math.3.8.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Accord.Statistics.3.8.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Deedle.1.2.5\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\DynamicInterop.0.7.4\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\FSharp.Date.0.3\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\MathNet.Numerics.4.4.1\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\numl.0.8.26.0\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\R.NET.Community.1.6.5\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\R.NET.Community.FSharp.1.6.5\lib\net40;C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Found assembly, checking version! (C:\Projects\bitbucket3\VSProjects\Fractal13\packages\RProvider.1.1.20\lib\net40\..\..\..\DynamicInterop.0.7.4\lib\net40\DynamicInterop.dll)
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] ...version matches, returning!
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] findRHomePath
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] getRLocation
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Scanning the registry
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] findRHomePath: file='C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.0\bin\x64\R.dll'
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:12476, Tid:44, Apid:1] generateTypes: getting packages
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:5, Apid:1] Adding work item to queue
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] server event loop: got work item
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] eval(.packages(all.available=T))
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] engine: Creating and initializing instance (sizeof<IntPtr>=8)
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] engine: Creating instance failed:
  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at RDotNet.SymbolicExpression..ctor(REngine engine, IntPtr pointer)
   at RDotNet.ExpressionVector.GetValue(Int32 index)
   at RDotNet.ExpressionVector.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at RDotNet.Vector`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RDotNet.REngine.Parse(String statement, StringBuilder incompleteStatement)
   at RDotNet.REngine.<Defer>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.LastOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RDotNet.REngine.Evaluate(String statement)
   at RDotNet.REngine.Initialize(StartupParameter parameter, ICharacterDevice device, Boolean setupMainLoop)
   at RDotNet.REngine.GetInstance(String dll, Boolean initialize, StartupParameter parameter, ICharacterDevice device)
   at RProvider.Internal.RInit.engine@119.Invoke() in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInit.fs:line 126
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Output: 
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:4948, Tid:1, Apid:1] Operation failed:
  System.Exception: Initialization of R.NET failed ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at RDotNet.SymbolicExpression..ctor(REngine engine, IntPtr pointer)
   at RDotNet.ExpressionVector.GetValue(Int32 index)
   at RDotNet.ExpressionVector.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at RDotNet.Vector`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RDotNet.REngine.Parse(String statement, StringBuilder incompleteStatement)
   at RDotNet.REngine.<Defer>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.LastOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RDotNet.REngine.Evaluate(String statement)
   at RDotNet.REngine.Initialize(StartupParameter parameter, ICharacterDevice device, Boolean setupMainLoop)
   at RDotNet.REngine.GetInstance(String dll, Boolean initialize, StartupParameter parameter, ICharacterDevice device)
   at RProvider.Internal.RInit.engine@119.Invoke() in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInit.fs:line 126
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RProvider.Internal.RInit.engine@119.Invoke() in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInit.fs:line 137
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at RProvider.RInteropInternal.eval@292.Invoke(Unit unitVar0) in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInterop.fs:line 293
   at RProvider.Internal.Logging.logWithOutput[a](CharacterDeviceInterceptor characterDevice, FSharpFunc`2 f) in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\Logging.fs:line 57
[5/26/2018 7:45:21 AM] [Pid:12476, Tid:44, Apid:1] RProvider constructor failed: System.Exception: Initialization of R.NET failed ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at RDotNet.SymbolicExpression..ctor(REngine engine, IntPtr pointer)
   at RDotNet.ExpressionVector.GetValue(Int32 index)
   at RDotNet.ExpressionVector.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at RDotNet.Vector`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RDotNet.REngine.Parse(String statement, StringBuilder incompleteStatement)
   at RDotNet.REngine.<Defer>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.LastOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RDotNet.REngine.Evaluate(String statement)
   at RDotNet.REngine.Initialize(StartupParameter parameter, ICharacterDevice device, Boolean setupMainLoop)
   at RDotNet.REngine.GetInstance(String dll, Boolean initialize, StartupParameter parameter, ICharacterDevice device)
   at RProvider.Internal.RInit.engine@119.Invoke() in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInit.fs:line 126
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at RProvider.Server.EventLoop.runServerCommandSafe[a](FSharpFunc`2 f) in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider\RInteropServer.fs:line 63
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at RProvider.Internal.IRInteropServer.GetPackages()
   at RProvider.RTypeBuilder.generateTypes@26-2.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next) in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider.DesignTime\RTypeBuilder.fs:line 27
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToList[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RProvider.RTypeBuilder.generateTypes@24-1.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next) in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider.DesignTime\RTypeBuilder.fs:line 25
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToList[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RProvider.RInteropClient.withServer[a](FSharpFunc`2 f) in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider.DesignTime\RInteropClient.fs:line 121
   at RProvider.RTypeBuilder.initAndGenerate@104.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next) in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider.DesignTime\RTypeBuilder.fs:line 109
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToList[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RProvider.RProvider.buildTypes() in C:\Tomas\Public\bmc\FSharp.RProvider\src\RProvider.DesignTime\RProvider.fs:line 32
```

Comment: Can you please share a log as described here: http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/diagnostics.html ?

Comment: @TomasPetricek - Thanks. I added the log to the body of the question.

Comment: Hmm, I'm really not sure what could be causing this. Sorry!

Comment: @TomasPetricek - Thanks for trying!

Comment: I have this same issue.

[7/11/2018 2:28:57 PM] [Pid:22864, Tid:1, Apid:1] engine: Creating and initializing instance (sizeof<IntPtr>=8)
[7/11/2018 2:28:57 PM] [Pid:22864, Tid:1, Apid:1] engine: Creating instance failed:
  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at RDotNet.SymbolicExpression..ctor(REngine engine, IntPtr pointer)
   at RDotNet.ExpressionVector.GetValue(Int32 index)
   at RDotNet.ExpressionVector.get_Item(Int32 index)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Resolved it by downgrading from R v3.5.0 to 3.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Resolved it by downgrading from R 4.0.3 to 3.4.4

- R v3.4.4
- RProvider v1.1.22
- VS Community 2019 v16.7.4
- Windows 10 Home